# Remote JUNIT for functional testing

Tags: java, junit

I would like to execute JUnit on a remote machine hosting a JVM embedded and linked to a C application through JNI. This JVM has state and access to live external resources and data which of course are not available in my build/test environment. In addition, my test/dev JVM is not linked to the C application and uses mock objects, so the behavior in test/live environments are totally different

My JUnit currently focus on unit testing but I would like to run functional on the live remote JVM. I had a look to TPTP but it seems to focus on profiling, I could not find any resources or help on this... Anyone with a similar problem? (of course I could build something ad-hoc but I'd rather save time...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Presumbly you can arrange to have some additional libraries added to that JVM's classpath? So you could get some initial "bootstrap" code in place.

I wonder whether you could adapt [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) for use here. I've only used for testing in the context of a servlet, but I think it could be adapted for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the tests directly at the command line on the remote machine, using e.g. Ant tasks, or Maven, or even the text-based junit TestRunner?

Or are you talking about an app deployed into some sort of app server, so that tests must be run in-container? More details would help.

Comment: Yes it's running in some sort of app server providing various services connected to databases and feeds... so clearly in container. TPTP sounded like something good but I'll have a look at cactus or building my own stuff on top of JUnit.